# Log all MySQL transactions on a per user basis

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP application that uses a single database for multiple users.  User log on, their ID is stored in a session, and they use the application to retrieve or update data in the database.

For security/archival purposes, I would like to log every SQL transaction on a per user basis.  Note that "user" is not a MySQL user as their is only uses one user.  How do I do this?

I am currently operating Centos 5.8, PHP 5.3.18, and MySQL 5.5.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET col = ?"
$db->prepare($sql);
//some params etc... 
$filename = '/dir/logs/log-' . $_SESSION['username'] . '';
$handle = fopen($filename, "wr");
$db->execute();
fwrite($handle, $sql);
```

It's a simple example, how you use the query either for execution and for writing in a file, named with the user. Well, used this way maybe you will get the content of $sql before the execution, but I think you got the idea.

P.S.: Thx for the edit :)

Comment: Why would you log to a file? Since you're already working with a database, log to a table which contains some extra fields like timestamp, user-id and the SQL statement (and possibly other useful fields) and store your SQL there. That way you can use SQL to filter on your log which surely is more powerful/flexible than storing it in files.

Comment: You might be right, but I think it should be on another database, since this one is used by multiple users, which, for sure have update right, and can easily manipulate the logs

Comment: He said PHP *application*, so there should be no direct write access by users since presumably the database is only accessed by the application.

Comment: Correct, the database is only accessed by the application.

Comment: Go for it then :) Replace the fopen/fwrite functions with query which inserts the stattement into a single column of a table, and some other things like `when` = NOW() and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can configure MySQL to produce a **[General query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html)** (GQL). This log, logs the established client connections and statements received from all clients. It is a regular text log file, which records every command against your DBMS, in the order they are received. It contains Timestamp, Id, Command and Arguments.

IP addresses and sessions are absent, since the database requests run locally, through the server. The timestamps allow a fairly precise matching with the IP entries of the client from your web server, i.e. the Apache httpd or Tomcat **[Access log file](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve)** (ALF).

We use GQL in order to enhance the sparse ALF information produced by GWT web applications.

This sample General query log should give you the idea:

```
110602 12:55:20     3 Connect   root@localhost on w2p
            3 Query /* mysql-connector-java-5.1.15 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} ) */SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name ='language' OR Variable_name = 'net_write_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'interactive_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'wait_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_client' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_connection' OR Variable_name = 'character_set' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_server' OR Variable_name = 'tx_isolation' OR Variable_name = 'transaction_isolation' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_results' OR Variable_name = 'timezone' OR Variable_name = 'time_zone' OR Variable_name = 'system_time_zone' OR Variable_name = 'lower_case_table_names' OR Variable_name = 'max_allowed_packet' OR Variable_name = 'net_buffer_length' OR Variable_name = 'sql_mode' OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_type' OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_size' OR Variable_name = 'init_connect'
110602 12:55:21     3 Query /* mysql-connector-java-5.1.15 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} ) */SELECT @@session.auto_increment_increment
            3 Query SHOW COLLATION
            3 Query SET NAMES utf8mb4
            3 Query SET character_set_results = NULL
            3 Query SET autocommit=1
            3 Query select * from user where username = 'asdasd' and password = 'aa'
            1 Query show global status
110602 12:55:25     1 Query show global status
110602 12:55:30 3 Query select * from user where username = 'costis' and password = 'snafu'
```

Comment: How would you recommend linking the GQL to actual user?  Would this be done by comparing it to the ALF?

Comment: Exactly. You get the IP-Address from the ALF and the username from the GQL.

Comment: I am ignorant regarding Tomcat ALF.  Need I learn?  I did look at my Apache /var/httpd/access_log file, and don't see how I can correlate it to the MYSQL log.

Comment: The httpd and the Tomcat ALF are very similar. You can configure them to report anything you need, according to your application. The GQL gives you the date, time and id of the MySQL requests. Parse these two files and match the information.

Comment: GQL logs every query including logon queries which pass username and passwords.  Ideally, I wouldn't create that liability.  Any workarounds?

Comment: Certainly! Check the manual of MySQL. You can keep the passwords in other files. Check also if the ALF can give you the information you need. The requested URL can be fairly analytical.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on and read [MySQL general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html). It contains ALL queries like this:

```
...
130404 19:02:50   476 Connect   test@localhost on test
          476 Query SET NAMES utf8
          476 Query SELECT * FROM `table1`
130404 19:02:52   476 Quit
130404 19:03:33   477 Connect   test@localhost on test
          477 Query SET NAMES utf8
...
```

The 476, 477, etc. are **MySQL thread ID**. Every new connection own it's ID.
All you need is to know **your user's thread id**. For PHP mysqli extension you can use [mysqli_thread_id()](http://php.net/mysqli_thread_id)

```
echo $_SESSION['username'].' '.
     date('Y-m-d H:i:s').' '.
     mysqli_thread_id($link);
```

Store this value to somewhere to match in log.

Comment: The MySQL thread ID is a good approach, but I am leery about using the MySQL General Query Log.